# publish private android apps using Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-enterprise, android-work-profile

This is possibly not a duplication. I have tried to find the solution. However I could not find any. My aim was to publish a private app in Google Play. What I have done is,

1. register an enterprise user https://enterprise.google.com/android/experience
2. Add user.
3. Get the Organization ID
4. Publish the app from Google Play using the Organization ID from "Pricing and Distribution" (since it was the same user (developer and enterprise), I just had to select that company).
5. The app was published and it was being shown in the app list in enterprise account

But the problem is, when I go to the work profile from the device. That app is not in the list of apps in the work profile.

** the app was published one day ago.

** the app has been enabled in enterprise account 4 hours ago.

** the app is just a sample app with blank activity.

Answer (score 0):

You get Google Play store app in work profile apps list. So you need to open it and search there you will get your published app for installation.
And also your app is not visible directly in the work profile app list because, I guess you set the Auto install option false while setting up apps for organisations.

[image]
See the attached image, you need to enable the Auto-Install option enable to get it.